# Condition to be conformal

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, conformal-geometry

I am looking at the following exercise:

Let $\Phi : U \rightarrow V$ be a diffeomorphism between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Write $$\Phi (u, v)=(f(u, v), g(u, v))$$ 
where $f$ and $g$ are smooth functions on the $uv$-plane.

Show that $\Phi$ is conformal if and only if

$$\text{ either } (f_u = g_v \text{ and }  f_v = −g_u) \text{ or }  (f_u = −g_v \text{ and }  f_v = g_u)$$

Show that, if $J(\Phi )$ is the Jacobian matrix of $\Phi$, then $\det (J(\Phi)) > 0$ in the first case and $\det (J(\Phi )) < 0$ in the second case.

$$$$

I have done the following:

$\Phi$ is conformal if and only if the first funamental form of $\Phi$ is $\lambda (du^2+dv^2$ for some smooth function $\lambda (u,v)$.

We have $$\Phi_u=\Phi_ff_u+\Phi_gg_u \ \text{ and } \ \Phi_v=\Phi_ff_v+\Phi_gg_v$$

$$E=\|\Phi_u\|^2=\|\Phi_ff_u+\Phi_gg_u \|^2=f_u^2\|\Phi_f\|^2+2f_ug_u\Phi_f\cdot \Phi_g+g_u^2\|\Phi_g\|^2\\ F=\Phi_u \cdot \Phi_v=f_uf_v\|\Phi_f\|^2+f_ug_v\Phi_f\cdot \Phi_g+f_vg_u\Phi_f\cdot \Phi_g+g_ug_v\|\Phi_g\|^2\\  G=\|\Phi_v\|^2=\|\Phi_ff_v+\Phi_gg_v \|^2=f_v^2\|\Phi_f\|^2+2f_vg_v\Phi_f\cdot \Phi_g+g_v^2\|\Phi_g\|^2$$

$$$$

$\Phi$ is coformal if and only if $E=G$ and $F=0$, so

$$f_u^2\|\Phi_f\|^2+2f_ug_u\Phi_f\cdot \Phi_g+g_u^2\|\Phi_g\|^2=f_v^2\|\Phi_f\|^2+2f_vg_v\Phi_f\cdot \Phi_g+g_v^2\|\Phi_g\|^2  \tag 1$$ $$\text{ and  } $$ 
$$\Phi_u \cdot \Phi_v=f_uf_v\|\Phi_f\|^2+f_ug_v\Phi_f\cdot \Phi_g+f_vg_u\Phi_f\cdot \Phi_g+g_ug_v\|\Phi_g\|^2=0 \tag 2$$

$$$$

$$(1) \Rightarrow (f_u^2-f_v^2)\|\Phi_f\|^2+2(f_ug_u-f_vg_v)\Phi_f\cdot \Phi_g+(g_u^2-g_v^2)\|\Phi_g\|^2=0 \tag 3$$

Adding the relations $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get $$(f_u^2+f_uf_v-f_v^2)\|\Phi_f\|^2+(2f_ug_u-2f_vg_v+f_ug_v+f_vg_u)\Phi_f\cdot \Phi_g+(g_u^2+g_ug_v-g_v^2)\|\Phi_g\|^2=0$$

$$$$

Is everything correct so far?

How could we continue?

Answer (score 0):

$\Phi$ is conformal is equivalent to saying that for every $x$ the Jacobian matrix is a similitude which is equivalent to saying that:

$Jac(\Phi_x)=\pmatrix{a_x &b_x\cr -b_x & a_x}$ or 
$Jac(\Phi_x)=\pmatrix{a_x &b_x\cr b_x & -a_x}$ since

$Jac(\Phi_x)=\pmatrix{\partial f_x &\partial f_y\cr \partial g_x & \partial g_y}$ you have the result.

Comment: Why is the fact that $\Phi$ is conformal equivalent to saying that for every $x$ the Jacobian matrix is a similitude?

Comment: This is exactly the condition that you have written.

Comment: The Jacobian matrix of $\Phi$ is $$J(\Phi)=\pmatrix{ f_u & f_v\cr  g_u &  g_v}$$ 

Which is the relation between this matrix and the terms of the first fundamental form $E,F,G$ ? I got stuck right now...

Comment: . The first fundamental form is the scalar product here and to be conformal means that the Jacobian is a conformal in respect to the scalar product.

Comment: The first fundamental form of $\Phi$ is $$\Phi_u\cdot \Phi_udu^2+\Phi_u\cdot \Phi_vdudv+\Phi_vdv^2$$ right? What do you mean by "the Jacobian is a conformal **in respect to the scalar product**" ?

Comment: yes it what I mean, but when you write this scalar product in $R^2$ you have the usual scalar product.

Comment: I got stuck right now, because at the first fundamental form we have the derivatives of $\Phi$ and at the Jacobian we have the derivatives of $f$...

Comment: What do you mean to write the scalar product in **$R^2$** ?